# Is a Docker/LXC container a running app or something in-memory?

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, lxc

I just read the excellent SO question asking ["*What is the difference between Docker and a VM?*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-io-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine). However, the accepted answer left me wanting just a wee bit more.

I *sort of* understand a container (Docker/LXC - I don't get the difference) to use something called `libcontainer` and AuFS so that dozens, hundreds, even thousands of containers can share the same CPU, RAM and disk resources. But, the answer still doesn't explain **exactly** what a "container" is!

Is a container just an instance of this `libcontainer` running? Is it an application that uses `libcontainer`? Is it something Linuxy like a service/daemon process? So I ask:

- What **exactly** is a "container"?
- What are the **exact** computing/system resources multiple containers can share inside the same VM/physical?
- Is Docker/LXC the "hypervisor" in the container equation? If not, what is the relationship between Docker, LXC and `libcontainer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the answer still doesn't explain exactly what a "container" is!

A container is basically a process, isolated, with all the environment it needs for its job (a webserver, a database, a CMS, any software...).

A container uses Linux kernel namespaces to isolate process, network and filesystems.
A container uses the concept of process isolation: filesystem, process, network, resource (CPU, memory),logging (STDIN...), shell isolation.

> Docker/LXC - I don't get the difference

LXC is a set of tools to control containers; Docker is another set of tools (all bundled into the same program), that also adds a file format so the contents of an 'image' can be passed around from machine to machine.  Docker is vastly more talked-about than LXC.
Docker used to use the lxc library to control containers, but replaced it with its own library called...libcontainer.

> What are the exact computing/system resources multiple containers can share inside the same VM/physical?

Containers on the same machine will share CPU, memory and the kernel.  Additionally, Docker lets you optionally have them share the same network.

> Is Docker/LXC the "hypervisor" in the container equation?

The Linux kernel is the real "hypervisor", and Docker/LXC are sending it commands to create and control containers.

Comment: See my other answer here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024213/docker-relationship-to-vms-and-lxc/28024797#28024797

Comment: Thanks @user2915097 (+1) - so to confirm what you're saying here: a Docker container is a Linux process/pid that *uses* this `libcontainer` library to take advantage of Linux kernel namespaces and process isolation? Does that sum it up? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, and this picture sums it well, virtual machines vs docker (at the bottom) https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker/